# How to use div with attribute in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, class

How to use `"<div class="example">"` in JavaScript code? I think compiler. JavaScript compiler understands it as `"<div class="` and `"example"`. On the other words, it do not correctly understands the order of double quotes.

Comment: "<div class=\"example\">" like this?

Comment: Do not replace one question with another one. Ask a new question.

Comment: Cannot make anymore questions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `'<div class="example">'` or `"<div class=\"example\">"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape character as "\" like this;

```
"<div class=\"example\">"
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!